# R shiny display formula

Tags: r, formula, shiny

I want to display correctly formula in Shiny title, like in Latex:

X_n=X_{n-1}-\varepsilon_n

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("Display formula in heading X_n=X_{n-1}-\varesilon"),

    sidebarPanel( ),

    mainPanel( )
  ))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `withMathJax`

```
require(shiny)
runApp(
  list(ui = pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel(withMathJax("$$\\text{Display formula in heading }X_n=X_{n-1}-\\varepsilon$$")),

  sidebarPanel( ),

  mainPanel( )
),
server= function(input, output, session){

}
)
```

)

[image: MathJax example]

Comment: thank you a lot! Could you help me please? I can't find function "withMathJax"

Comment: You need shiny v0.9.0 or greater. I am running 0.9.1 http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shiny/index.html

Comment: Doesn't work on R version 3.4.2. Text is printed as sequence of symbols, not the formula.